# Is there any other word for negative species traits?

Tags: word-request

I'm currently trying to describe a few species traits and group them. Here I found that I'm at a loss of correct words for the groupings. After searching a bit I found a good fitting with "beneficial traits" for traits that are enhancing specific races like extra sharp teeth, or the ability to fly.

But on the "other" side I have found no wordings that sounded fitting for negative species traits like a vulnerability to cold (as many snakes have).

So my question here is is there any such word for negative species traits?

Comment: We don't use *race* and *racial* of any animal except humans.

Comment: @StoneyB tnx edited it. In my case racial would have been fitting as the text I'm writing is about different races in a RPG, but as that is not really of any importance to the question per se, I've changed it and replaced racial,... with species.

Comment: @Sto We do, though your point is well-taken. :-) Aside from uses like the game mentioned: BIOLOGY
a population within a species that is distinct in some way, especially a subspecies.
"people have killed so many tigers that two races are probably extinct". Google define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geneticists, physical anthropologists, and other biologists, etc., use *maladaptive* to describe such traits.

*A maladaptive trait* is a common expression.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maladaptation

Answer (score 0):

The decriptor you might be looking for is

> genetic
>
> genetic *vulnerability*
>   inherent *vulnerability*

meaning a vulnerability which is passed down from one generation to another and "built-in".

> Sickle cell anemia is considered a **genetic vulnerability** outside of malaria regions.
>   Chinese women are less **genetically vulnerable** to breast cancer.

Usually additional context is needed to link the defect or vulnerability to a particular race.

> Snakes are susceptible to cold weather because they are **genetically** cold blooded.

> Lower levels of skin cancer is a **genetic trait** among Blacks and people with darker skin color.

Comment: Could one of these be used in combination with the word "trait"? (Would be prefered but as I overlooked to mention that in the question itself this answer is good even so....I won't edit my question as that would be unfair now).

Comment: Yes, a trait is passed down through genes, additonal example in question.

Comment: A "defect", particularly a "genetic defect" is usually an *abnormality*, though.  I think Thomas is asking more about "*normal*, but *detrimental*" genetic traits.  For example, sickle-cell anemia is more common among people with African descent, a consequence of genetic traits that increase resistance to malaria.

Comment: @Andrew I was thinking in terms of defects then being passed down, but you are correct that a **defect** originally is an abnormality.  For example, people with near-sightedness generally have near-sighted offspring, but the acquisition of  near-sightedness occurs within a single  generation (when the defect occurs).  Congenital blindness is a **defect** but does not necessarily get passed down.